# speed up pandas pd.to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing Dataframe to file using pandas. here is my snippet

```
df.to_csv(filename, sep=",")
```

it is taking 1 minute,20 seconds for 1.14 GB

is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for. [Click here to Visit GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12885)

Answer (score -1):

This could significantly reduce the write time. Please try and feed back.

```
stage.to_csv('output.csv.gz'
     , sep='|'
     , header=True
     , index=False
     , chunksize=100000
     , compression='gzip'
     , encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: This really isn't a useful answer, you don't explain which of these *should* reduce the write time, and for example, I don't think `chunksize` will do anything but slow you down, and compression will possibly slow you down as well